# ¿Cómo aplicar colores condicionales a filas en odoo 9?

Tags: vistas, odoo

Dentro de un form view, he puesto un notebook y dentro una page pero no consigo mostrar colores en base al value de un field, esto es lo que llevo pero no me pinta el color gris:

```
<notebook>
    <page name="forecast_records" string="Forecast Records">
        <field name="forecast_product_ids" nolabel="1" context="{'active_rec_id':active_id}" domain="[('period_start_date','=', forecast_filter_id)]" attrs="{'readonly': [('state','in',['done'])]}">
            <tree string="Forecast" editable="top" delete="false" create="false">
                <field name="id" invisible='1'/>
                <field name="product_id" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="prestashop_product_id" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="sales" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="days_unavailable" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="percentage_unavailable" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="forecast_qty"/>
                <field name="onhand_qty" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="available_for_sale" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="incoming_qty" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="outgoing_qty" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="action_qty" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="action_required"/>
                <field name="document_number" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="procurement_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo provee algunos algunos atributos para la etiqueta tree los cuales son:

- decoration-info
- decoration-muted
- decoration-danger
- decoration-warning
- decoration-bf

Segun la condicion que coloques te mostrara algun u otro color, no recuerdo que colores da cada atributo pero puedes probarlos, un ejemplo de uso seria asi:

```html
<tree decoration-info"state=='done'">
```